# Ruby Mixin / Rails Concern share variable between all including classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

I'm trying to create a concern that holds fields mapping from including classes. Then I need to perform actions based on the data of all mappings. This is a simplification of what I currently have:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
  end

  def self.mapped_fields
    # _ = [Test, Test2]
    @@all_fields
  end

  class_methods do
    def add_field(name)
      @@all_fields ||= []
      @@all_fields << name 
    end
  end

end

class Test
  include MyConcern
  
  add_field :test
end

class Test2
  include MyConcern
  
  add_field :test_2
end

puts MyConcern.mapped_fields
# => [:test, :test_2]
```

Although, if I don't eager load the including classes `_ = [Test, Test2]`, the `@@all_fields` variable is never touched. This makes it impractical to use in development (I suppose it would work fine in production since all classes are eager loaded by default).

What makes me wonder if this is the correct way to do it ? Seems weird.. Rubocop says I should replace all class variables with class instance variables (rule Style/ClassVars) but I don't know how to have the same effect with it.

Is there a better way to do this ? I had done it storing the mappings into the database in my first attempt. But it seemed unnecessary since all mappings are defined in a declarative manner, it also makes it necessary to mirror the mappings into the database, adding complexity. So I wanted to take advantage of ruby's features for that.

**EDIT a bit more context on the original problem**

The Concern in question is meant to track a lot of database columns that have blank values set, in order to suggest the user to fill them out. The Concern add triggers for update/create/destroy to the models including it, which check the fields defined using the `add_field` method mentioned above, but the non-simplified version looks like this

```
add_fields fields: {
    FIELD_ONE: { filled: ->(parent) { parent&.field_one.present? } }
}
```

After I have the mappings set up, I can just run all `filled` Procs for a user, and present the blank fields to the frontend. The specific problem that this solution doesn't work well for, is to have the list of Procs that should be run (in order to obtain the missing fields that I should suggest to the users).

Comment: I think your gut feel is correct... this does "seem weird". Can you store this value(s) in the database?

Comment: I had done it storing the mappings in db in the first attempt. But it seemed unnecessary since all mappings are defined in a declarative manner, so I wanted to take advantage of ruby for that. Maybe I should have opened a question here before changing it  lol

Comment: Note that, during development, your classes will also be continually unloaded and reloaded, leading to duplicates being added to `@@all_fields`.

Comment: There isn't really an answerable question here. What you're doing is fine, but as you say, it only works if you actually include (manually, or via autoload) the files that define classes which include the module. Whatever you're trying to do here, it probably is not well-suited to an environment with autoloaded classes.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There might be another solution to solve the original problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: What **is** the original problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a class to hold variable information like this.  I would aim for a singleton or something like it.  Here is some scribbling:

```
class SharedFields
  attr_reader :shared_array

  def self.instance
    Thread.current[:SharedFields] ||= new
  end

  def initialize
    @shared_array = []
  end
end

...

class Test
  def in
    SharedFields.instance.shared_array << :foo
  end

  def out
    SharedFields.instance.shared_array
  end
end

test = Test.new
test.in
test.out # [:foo]
test.in
test.out # [:foo, #foo]
```

You get the picture.  No class variables.  Looks like it might be thread safe.  You have an obvious place to stub/mock in tests.  If you need to do tricky things to some part of the relationship you can.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will have a look at using Thread.current to share data. But I think this wouldn't solve the part of having to initialise all mapped classes prior to having a complete array of mappings. Of course I couldn't add to the array when creating an instance either.